# getting same message in android GCM

Tags: android, .net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My android app getting same message like "you got message". Even though i'm changing data in server side.

Server-Side code(dot net):

```
string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
                + Label1.Text + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";
```

have to make any changes in GCM app code?

```
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        //String message = intent.getExtra("message"); 
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

On seraching google i found something that we have to replace this

```
String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
```

with

```
String message = intent.getExtra("message");
```

but i am getting error like this "The method getExtra(String) is undefined for the type Intent".Please guide me that what i'm missing in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

instead of

```
String message = intent.getExtra("message");
```

for Getting String Message from Intent

**EDIT :**

if you are receive data in Bundle instance then change your code as because getExtra is not a method in Intent class :

```
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras("bundle_Name_here");
```

now retrieve all value from bundle using key

Comment: if the message was processed correctly, the code mentioned above will return the message text

Comment: @user1842744 : first think  getExtra is not method of Intent . it is intent.getExtras("bundle_name") if you want to retrieve bundle from Intent

Comment: k. i'm sending data from server.The same data should appear in application.How it is?

Comment: @user1842744 : this is out of question scope but use AsyncTask for getting data from server and in onpostexecute update your ui from new data returned from server . and for more help make a new question for this issue to get better or good answer.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your  **HTTP POST**:

```
data.notId="2"
```

For each different notId it will be threated as a different message. I had the same problem for a long time, now I would like to group those messages.